# The calling thread must be an STA thread because it is required by many UI components with livechart

Tags: c#, multithreading, livecharts

Maybe my qustion is duplicate but actually I tried the other solutions and couldn't solve the problem. The Plot form is not my main form, but it opens from main form. in the main program, i have the [STAThread] before Main(). I want to run Ploting() priodically to update the plot if any changes in the data in sql table happens. 
my code is as follows:

```
namespace MainProject1{
  public partial class Plot : Form
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    BackgroundWorker PlotWorker;  

    public Plot()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

        PlotWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        PlotWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(PlotWorker_DoWork);
        PlotWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        //Ploting(); //here it works
    }

    void PlotWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        while (true)
        {
            //Ploting(); //here also receive the error.
            if (PlotWorker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArg)
    {
        Ploting(); //here i receive the error
    }

    private void test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Interval = 100;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Ploting()
    {
        try
        {
            var list1 = new List<double>();
            var list2 = new List<double>();

            SqlResultTable rt = new SqlResultTable();
            rt.ReadtoPlot(84, "readingS", ref list1, ref list2); //here i read the data from sql. it works corrrect.
            cartesianChart1.Series = new SeriesCollection
            {
                new ScatterSeries
                {
                    Title = "Setpoints",
                    Values = new ChartValues<double>(list1),
                    PointGeometry = DefaultGeometries.Diamond,
                    StrokeThickness = 2,
                    Fill = Brushes.Transparent,
                },
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Title = "UUT readings",
                    Values = new ChartValues<double>(list2),
                    LineSmoothness = 0,
                    PointGeometrySize = 10
                },
            };
            cartesianChart1.DataClick += CartesianChart1OnDataClick;
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }

    private void CartesianChart1OnDataClick(object sender, ChartPoint chartPoint)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked (" + chartPoint.X + "," + chartPoint.Y + ")");
    }
}
```

}

when I use the Ploting() method in the constructor, it works, but when I use it in worker or in timer_Elapsed I receive the error again. I know that it has something to do with thread but don't know how to solve it. I tried to create new thread in background worker or timer_Elapsed, but received another error.
Sorry for the qustion. I'm new in C#!

New update: code with delegation:

```
  namespace MainProject1{
  public partial class Plot : Form
{
    public delegate void plotDel(); //**** new added ***
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    BackgroundWorker PlotWorker;  

    public Plot()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

        PlotWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        PlotWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(PlotWorker_DoWork);
        PlotWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        plotDel pl1 = OnPlotNeeded; //**** new added ***
        //Ploting(); //here it works
    }

    protected virtual void OnPlotNeeded()  //**** new added ***
    {
        Ploting();
    }
    void PlotWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        while (true)
        {
            //Ploting(); //here also receive the error.
            if (PlotWorker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArg)
    {
        System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(o => Ploting()), null); //when i add this line, it does not go to next line(no error, no action) and without it, again receive the error as before!
        OnPlotNeeded();
    }

    private void test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Interval = 100;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Ploting()
    {
        // the inside code is same as first code
    }

    private void CartesianChart1OnDataClick(object sender, ChartPoint chartPoint)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked (" + chartPoint.X + "," + chartPoint.Y + ")");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Standard error, many google hits.  Using a component or library on a worker thread requires it to be thread-safe.  The exception tells you that it *explicitly* says it is not safe.  So you can't use it in a worker.

Comment: Hi there! Need some debuging. Set a breakpoint at `Ploting()` call and check which apartment is setted on a thread, that is calling this method, STA or MTA. Use this code in immediate window of visual studio `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState`

Comment: This is a common error when working with multiple threads in .NET. No need to downvote...

Comment: @vasily thanks. I checked at the point of calling Ploting(). it is MTA

Comment: so it is calling from MTA thread, which is wrong. Possible solution is in answer below.

Comment: @vasily.sib thanks for your comment. still have problem with it. explaned in the comments of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is presumably that `timer_Elapsed` is not executed on the UiThread (actually that is what the exception is trying to say you). But you can delegate the call to `Ploting()` back to the UiThread.

Try this variant of `timer_Elapsed`

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArg)
{
    System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(delegate { this.Ploting(); }, null);
}
```

And also replace all other calls to `Plotting()` with the delagation.

Edit:
Save the `SynchronizationContext` on creation in a class-variable like

```
private readonly SynchronizationContext syncContext;

public Plot()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.syncContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;
    ...
}
```

And call `Plotting()` with this context like so:

```
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) => this.DelagetePloting();

private void DelagetePloting()
    => this.syncContext.Post(delegate
    {
        this.Ploting();
    }, null);

private void Ploting()
{
    // your work
}
```

Comment: actually I'm still confused. I replaced timer_Elapsed with above one, but Ploting() is not being called any more.

Comment: This is odd... can you confirm that `timer_Elapsed` is called? The invocation of `Ploting()` might also be delayed since `Post()` dispatches an asynchronous message to its synchronization context. You could try `Send()` instead.

Comment: actually I'm still confused. About delegation. All the examples that i find on internet, are declaring and using delegates in different classes. But here I have to do both in my form class (I edited the code, is that true?). I replaced timer_Elapsed with above one, but Ploting() is not being called any more.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I placed a breakpoint on OnPlotNeeded() and also on the line before. I comes to first line, but never goes to OnPlotNeeded(). I tested Send(). same result.

Comment: added the answer hope it helps. The problem with my first solution is that the worker Thread doesn't have a `SynchronizationContext` so you need to hold on to the one you got on creation. When I tested my first solution I got a NullReferenceException, did you too?

Comment: about `comes to first line, but never goes to OnPlotNeeded()` problem: place breakpoint at methods closing bracket. Looks like `SynchronizationContext.Post()` never returns.